# Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 device manager emulator is broken and distorted

Tags: android

I run the android emulator and it seems distorted and i tried different vitual phones and gets same glitch...
Thanks for any comments in advance.

I tried different android SDK and virtual phone and the problem was the same maybe its related about my graphic card or intel-haxm.I don't know but maybe some one encountered same glitch...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I use until an bug fixed Emulator is available to use with Dolphin

To Start an AVD I use Arctic Fox and then close Arctic Fox and open Dolphin and the emulator connects to logcat over adb automatically.
Use the zip files for installing Android Studio side by side.

If in Dolphin I create a new AVD it works,
but on next restart of PC -> Dolphin -> AVD Manager -> Start the same emulator.
The emulator start times out after 300ms, sometimes even corrupt the emulator system image and I have to try Wipe Data to get it started, but that creates a new Device, and old Device is lost forever.

Further digging points to something to do with gRPC

Tested on Emulator version: 31.1.4
There seems to be an update available(31.3.14) but will not risk it of loosing the ability to start Emulator at all (happened when Android 12 system image was released for QEMU, Emulator started becoming dependant on Vulkan, updating HAXM fixed it)

Somethings was clearly broken in the emulator and are being fixed
31.3.10 https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#31-3-10
31.3.11 https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#31-3-11

If you want to revert to other emulator versions, you can find the emulator setups here
https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

UPDATE 1:
Run the emulator from command line with to find the detailed issue `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator/emulator -avd <NameOfAVD> -verbose -show-kernel`

Mine is stuck in a boot loop

```
[   58.526191] init: Reboot ending, jumping to kernel
[   58.754699] reboot: Restarting system with command 'boringssl-self-check-failed'
[   58.778271] reboot: machine restart
```

UPDATE 2:
There appears to be an issue open with the emulator team at Google about this
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256418219

UPDATE 3:
Workaround suggested for now by team at Google working on this
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/226929286#comment6

> the best immediate option is to use a GoogleAPI system image or to
> never sign in into the PlayStore.

Issue was reproduced on Emulator v31.1.4 and v31.3.14 with Android system image with Google Play Store - Android 12.0 (API 31) - x86_64